# How to set the auxiliary disk cache programmatically using jcs

Tags: java, caching, jcs

I am obtaining my cache object like this

```
CacheAccess<Object, Object> cache = JCS.getInstance("queries");
```

I have put a config file in the classpath cache.ccf. For debugging reasons I want to set the aux disk cache path programmatically, but do not know how to obtain the interface I need. I know there exsists an attribute class where one may set this path, but I do not know how to get the instance of this class which refers to the cache I am using. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you found a solution to your problem? I'm facing the same one