# JCS auxiliary cache disk path configuration

Tags: java, caching, apache-commons, jcs

I'm using JCS 2.0 in order to create a cache system for my web application.

Since this application will run in different servers, which may have different home paths, I'd like to know if there's a method to programmatically change the disk path for the cache, or the only solution is to create a different `cache.ccf` file for each installation.

I've found only these 2 question regarding the argument:

1. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15297855/jcs-edit-disk-auxiliary-cache-diskpath) refers to the 1.3 version, and I don't know if can be used in my case
2. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31706419/how-to-set-the-auxiliary-disk-cache-programmatically-using-jcs) seems the same question as mine, but has no answer.

Thanks in advance